# How can I create an ecs service for my deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, github-actions

I’m learning CI/CD pipelines and I’ve come up with a question.

I have a CloudFormation file that creates some static resources for my app (ECR repository, ECS Cluster and some roles)

When creating my deployment pipeline in GitHub Actions I’ve set up my task-definition.json to run my ECS Task.

But when do I create my ECS Service?
Should it be already created or I need to create in the deployment stage?

If it needs to be already created in my CloudFormation template, how will I put a task definition resource pointing to an empty ECR?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, your guess is right. You need to create the service in advance with a task definition pointing to your empty ECR, clearly this won't go up, but once you run your pipeline, a new task definition will be created pointing to your newly created image and update the service.